# Azure signalR and microservices

Tags: .net, azure, signalr, azure-signalr

I’m quite confused and want some clarification

I’ve got a number of microservices which sit behind an api gateway.

I’ve got a react webApp which interacts with these apis via the gateway

The react app currently polls the API’s at a set interval to update or refresh its view of the world

Our client now wishes to have a more real-time approach. The simple solution here is to move to azure signalR backed with azure functions.

2 things.

1. how does each api then tell this signalR service to send an update?
2. is this best practice? Or should I have a signalR instance in each microservice? To me that sounds like a bad design? Since the gateway would be publishing a socket endpoint for each service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to use one hub. The microservices behind the gateway would be clients of the hub. The applications that connect to the gateway would also be clients of the hub.

The microservices would not be in the same group/groups as the client applications.

When the services have an update they message the hub. A method on the hub then sends that to the group(s) of applications that consume the services.

This would be a much simpler design than making every one of your services into a SignalR hub.

Comment: Brilliant. That kinda makes some sense. They’re both consumers. 

What doesn’t make sense is ‘api gateway is the hub’. What does this mean? What does this look like? 

I’m using ocolot has the gateway.

Comment: It would probably be better to add the hub separately, on second thoughts. I was imagining the API Gateway as a facade that you had implemented that could be swapped out easily for a hub accomplishing the same thing. Even in that case there would be no need to replace it though.

Comment: When you say add separately? Again I’m not sure what you mean by this? I’d be trying to use azure signalR. I assume I can just use that has the hub? Get all clients to connect to it?

Comment: I've updated my answer, which I hope makes my thoughts more clear.

Comment: So in theory I can stand up a new web application with a signalR hub. All clients (both web apps and apis) can connect and use the messaging style group room chat features.

Comment: Yes. You use groups to define which clients to broadcast to.